# Getting Overall row total in column total

Tags: ssrs-2008

I have a Matrix and I need to get the total rows so I can perform a percentage.

This is a rough matrix layout

[MyDataSet]

[MyParentGroupRow]

[ColumnA] [ColumnB] [ColumnC] - [Row Total]

[Column Total A] [Column Total B] [Column Total c] - [Overall Total Rows]

So I need to take [Column Total x] / [Overall Total Rows]

I can't seem to get the [Overall Total Rows value]. If I use the root dataset it will be wrong because the Tablix is filtered. So I need to get the total rows for [MyParentGroupRow].

Notes.
I can't change the dataset.
Everything is a count of rows. So I can't use things like sum.

Comment: What about using the Tablix name as the Scope, not the Dataset?

Comment: I think I have tried that. I will try it again and let you know.